# Updating Highstock chart points

Tags: highcharts

I need to update the most recent candle in my chart. Typically, I would use this to update a point:

```
//javascript
chart.series[0].data[n].update({...});
```

However, my series.data array is empty when I show the entire data set possibly because of:

> **Official HighStock Documentation: data**
>
> Read only. An array with the series' data point objects. In case the series data length exceeds the cropThreshold, or if the data is grouped, series.data doesn't contain all the points. It only contains the points that have been created on demand. In these cases, all original X and Y values can be read from series.xData and series.yData. Additionally, series.options.data contains all configuration objects for the points, whether they be numbers, arrays or objects.
>
> Returns Array

How can I update my most recent candle point when the interface to the Point.update method is only accessible via the series.data collection? When my series.data array is empty do I just overwrite the point properties via series.options.data?

I've also considered invoking the series.update(options) method, but I may need to perform a candle update many times as a result of real time activity. Therefore, an update on the entire series object would not be a good decision because of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The data array is empty because Highstock does data grouping - when enabled it uses groupedData array instead. Unfortunately, you cannot update a grouped point (Highcharts throws the [error](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/24)).

What you can do, is disabling data grouping, then you will get a data array and point.update is possible or use [Series.removePoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.removePoint) and [Series.addPoint()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint)

```
 chart.series[0].removePoint([chart.series[0].groupedData.length - 1]);
      chart.series[0].addPoint([
        Date.UTC(2016, 11, 8),
        115,
        2,
        30,
        20
      ]);
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/0z95x58t/